# How do I save, start, stop my virtual machine created using Vagrant?

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox

I am taking the Udacity Deep Learning course and found a great link that got me up and started using vagrant:

https://medium.com/@Rapchik/running-google-s-deep-learning-course-material-under-windows-82d468b6d5be#.8acsjam1c. I created an instance and used docker

I know next to nothing about vagrant and used VMWarePlayer and Virtual Box in the past.

Now that I have everything setup I want to save the current state and comeback as needed to do assignments and reference the materials. How do I start, stop and save. Thanks very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You work with `vagrant` using the command line interface. The documentation below should help you but i'll cover a few basics.

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/

*You need to run these commands inside the folder you have your Vagrantfile in. Without a vagrantfile, `vagrant` doesn't know what instance to act upon!*

- `vagrant up` will start your vagrant instance. If you run it twice, don't worry, it will only start one instance.
- `vagrant halt` will stop your vagrant instance. There's no way to save the state of a vagrant instance, so you may need to halt instead, but any changes you make will be saved.
- `vagrant ssh` to access the command line interface of the vagrant instance. This is used maybe for debugging webserver logs or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

vargant suspend, then vagrant up ... why did I not google more!

Answer (score -2):

```
vagrant validate
vagrant status

vagrant up --provision
vagrant halt
vagrant suspend
vagrant destroy -f
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.